# How do you determine the order of columns in a (filtered) index for a query with joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2012

I have a query that is hard coded in an application, in old ANSI style, but I hope to optimise with an appropriate filtered index.

```
SELECT HISTORY.UNITS 
FROM branch, detail, HISTORY --WITH(INDEX(test))
WHERE   
    HISTORY.DETAIL_ID = detail.ID 
    AND HISTORY.BRANCH_ID = branch.ID
    AND HISTORY.WEEK_SELECTOR=123456 
    AND (branch.BRANCH_CODE='016') 
    AND (detail.CODE='01308054')
```

I have tried a filtered index on HISTORY and switched the columns around to no avail. Branch and Detail are small tables but HISTORY is very large.

```
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [test] ON [HISTORY]
    (
        [WEEK_SELECTOR] ASC,
        [DETAIL_ID] ASC,
        [BRANCH_ID] ASC
    )
    INCLUDE ([UNITS]) 
    WHERE ([week_selector]=(123456))
```

When I force it to try to use the index I get:

> Msg 8622, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Query processor could not produce
>   a query plan because of the hints defined in this query. Resubmit the
>   query without specifying any hints and without using SET FORCEPLAN.

Please can someone tell me how to work out the correct order, taking the JOINs and WHERE clause into consideration?

Comment: Is this correct query? I don't know what `product_detail.SKU_ID`

Comment: Good eye. I had to change the column names to protect proprietary information. It should be correct now.

Comment: Isn't the presence of `WEEK_SELECTOR` logically redundant in that index's column set?

Comment: There are 500m rows in history but 99.99% of querying is done on the recent week, this week having code:123456. I want to create a filtered index each week.

Comment: Have you considered partitioning rather than creating a filtered index? That sounds more akin to what you're describing.

Comment: @Xedni it is not Enterprise and I have no authorisation to make such changes. I can only use indexing to make improvements.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean That has already been done.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean There is no query to be optimised. Above is my query and my filtered composite index which doesn't work. I just want the correct order of columns and inclusions. There is no other scope.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT HISTORY.UNITS 
FROM HISTORY
INNER JOIN branch
    ON branch.ID = HISTORY.BRANCH_ID
INNER JOIN detail
    ON detail.ID = HISTORY.DETAIL_ID
WHERE   
    HISTORY.WEEK_SELECTOR = 123456 
    AND branch.BRANCH_CODE = '016'
    AND detail.CODE = '01308054';
```

I would personally never use query hints in a production environment. Indexes I'd use:

- `detail(CODE, ID)`
- `branch(BRANCH_CODE, ID)`
- `HISTORY(WEEK_SELECTOR, BRANCH_ID, DETAIL_ID)` with included `UNITS` column

I'm not certain about your data, but you might have to swap around `DETAIL_ID` and `BRANCH_ID` for better performance gains.

Comment: As I said in the post: the query is hard-coded in an application. All I can do is index the HISTORY table.

Comment: Well, I've rewritten query into a proper ANSI syntax, logically there's nothing different. Why cannot you index other two tables?

Comment: They only have a hundred or so rows in each.

Comment: Well, this doesn't add much, but seeks are always better than table scans and can help for query optimizer. So just index these two the way I suggested and index HISTORY table using your filter and those three columns + included column

Comment: I still get the hints error when I try to force the index WEEK_SELECTOR, BRANCH_ID, DETAIL_ID.

Comment: Don't force index seek and attach execution plan here.